# How to match any one of several possible values in a range, and filter matches by another value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup, index-match

Essentially, I am working to compare 3 tables. I know my way around XLOOKUP, FILTER, INDEX, and MATCH but not, apparently, enough to manipulate them the way I'm trying to! If this is something that just needs to be a VBA or Python script, let me know.

1. Is a list of products that are missing from a customer.
2. Is a list of parent products (I'll call them bundles from here on for clarity). Each child product may belong to one or more bundles.
3. Is a list of bundles owned by a specific customer.

Let's call my 3 tables Table1, Table2, and Table3.

- Table1 has 2 columns, A and B, containing a product name and a customer name
- Table2 has 2 columns, A and B, containing a product name and a bundle name
- Table3 has 2 columns, A and B, containing a bundle name and a customer name

I need to find, for each product in Table 1, whether or not the customer owns any bundle that contains the product. I don't need to return a specific match out of the list, just the first one I find for the customer. But, I keep running into situations where I have to nest array formulas inside of other array formulas and can't quite get there on my own.

Here is what I have tried so far:

- FILTER(). I was able to filter the range of bundles to get a list of all possible bundles for a given product like so: `=FILTER('Table2'!A:A,'Table2'!B:B='Table1'!A2)`. But from there it all went downhill...
- Tried to XLOOKUP this list of selected bundles against the customer's bundles like so: `=XLOOKUP(FILTER('Table2'!A:A,'Table2'!B:B='Table1'!A2), 'Table3'!A:A, 'Table3'!A:A)`. This finds me a match for each bundle, but doesn't find me a match that belongs to the given customer in 'Table1'!B2.
- So then I tried the Boolean trick with XLOOKUP to do multiple comparisons: `=XLOOKUP(1, (FILTER('Table2'!A:A,'Table2'!B:B='Table1'!A2)='Table3'!A:A) * ('Table3'!A:A=B2), 'Table3'!A:A)`. Unfortunately now I get a `#N/A` error.

I tried several more variations of this using INDEX and MATCH instead, using a nested FILTER, but all led to the same dead end. I just can't wrap my head around how to filter a range by another range + some other criteria (the customer name). Can anyone point me the right direction?

**EDIT:** I tried a new approach, doing a separate filter for bundles that belong to the customer: `=FILTER('Table3'!A:A,'Table3'!B:B='Table1'!B2)`. So now, I have two arrays - one of the possible bundle matches, and another of the bundles the customer owns. But still can't figure out how to inner join those two lists using a formula.

Comment: Post few of your sample data and then show your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have used a few parameters in a `LET` function here

First `FILTER` the product/bundle table to find which bundles match the product

Next `FILTER` the bundle/customer table to find which bundles match the customer

Then `MATCH` the results of the first `FILTER` against the second `FILTER` to see if any product bundles match any customer bundles. Wrap that in `IFERROR` to handle cases where there is no match, and `MAX` to only get 1 matching bundle.

Then use `INDEX` to get the name of the matching bundle, and wrap that in `IF` in case there is no matching bundle.

```
=LET(PRODBUND,FILTER(Table2[Bund],Table2[Prod]=[@Prod]),
CUSTBUND,FILTER(Table3[Bund],Table3[Cust]=[@Cust]),
MAXBUND,MAX(IFERROR(MATCH(PRODBUND,CUSTBUND,0),0)),
IF(MAXBUND=0,"No match",INDEX(CUSTBUND,MAXBUND)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your formula would indicate you are using 3 different sheets, not tables. Here is a solution using tables.

Your first step with `FILTER` to get a list of matching bundles works fine.

From there you can use `COUNTIFS` to see how many rows in Table3 match the customer and each bundle.

Finally use `SUM` and `>0` to check if there was any match for any of the bundles.

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Table3[Bund],FILTER(Table2[Bund],Table2[Prod]=[@Prod]),Table3[Cust],[@Cust]))>0
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This works great for finding them which is farther than I was able to get on my own - but the piece that's missing is that I want to return one of these matching bundles. Is there a way I could use an array function to find the matches? Then I could just use @ to grab the first one?